# Can the below negative equation be converted to a positive equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$x+iy=\sqrt { \frac { a+ib }{ c+id }  }$$, prove that $$(x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 })^{ 2 }=\frac { { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } }{ { c }^{ 2 }+{ d }^{ 2 } } $$ 
Solving by myself, I have got this:
$$(x^{ 2 }-y^{ 2 })^{ 2 }=\frac { { a }^{ 2 }-{ b }^{ 2 } }{ { c }^{ 2 }-{ d }^{ 2 } } $$
Can this be changed to what is required or this approach is itself wrong?

Comment: It would be easier to comment on your approach if you showed what you do to arrive at the result you say you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $(x+iy)^2(c+id) = a+ib \implies |x+iy|^2|c+id| = |a+ib|$, and square both sides with note that $|m+in| = \sqrt{m^2+n^2}$.